# Apache configuration proxy pass

Tags: apache

I want to configure a server to listen to localhost adress with proxy pass.
 Fist, I added a proxy pass configuration like that:

```
ProxyPass         /test  http://localhost:5959/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /test  http://localhost:5959/
ProxyPassReverse  /test  http://domain_name.net/
```

The index is working fine, but the problem is when i click on some button to be redirected to another page. I expected the redirection would be like : http://domaine_name.net/test/anotherpage.php but it didn't work.

I tried another configuration but it didn't work

```
ProxyPass         /test/  http://localhost:5959/test/
ProxyPassReverse  /test/ http://localhost:5959/test/
ProxyPassReverse  /test/  http://domain_name.net/test/
```

How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not put 2 `ProxyPassReverse` directives.  Only one.  And it should match the `ProxyPass` destination.  So your first `ProxyPassReverse` only is required.

```
ProxyPass         /test  http://localhost:5959/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /test  http://localhost:5959/
```

From the documentation for `ProxyPassReverse`, (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse):

> This directive lets Apache httpd adjust the URL in the Location,
>   Content-Location and URI headers on HTTP redirect responses. [...]

---

You said in your question:

> I expected the redirection would be like :
>   http://domaine_name.net/test/anotherpage.php but it didn't work.

this is normal.  A proxy hides the final destination server to the client.  If you want to **redirect** the client, do not use a proxy.  Use mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule` and others).

Comment: The mod_rewrite needs a directory to work. I am using directly the localhost address in the server. For example, I installed phpmyadmin and it should be working in the normal configuration like localhost/phpmyadmin or 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin, it is working. If I want to access to phpmyadmin from outside the server like using http://domain_name.net/phpmyadmin, it works when I am using the config 
ProxyPass /test http://localhost:5959/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse /test http://localhost:5959/
But the problem is when I write the login and put the redirection can not be established to the index page.

Comment: The answer I provided is to proxy `/test` to `localhost:5959`, nothing else.  But that is what is in the question right?  If you need to proxy other URI, the ProxyPass needs to be modified (of other rules are required).  If the `/test` portion is solved, please approve the answer, and post the other issue (phpmyadmin) as a different question.  Note that this phpmyadmin issue is quite common, some research here (or on the web) might help you without having to post.